# How can I get the carousel indicator buttons to respond when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, indicator

I am unable to scroll through the images using the indicator buttons that are located below the carousel. After combing through the code several times, I realize the difficulty stems from not being able to connect the carousel class to the indicator buttons. I have tried making the carousel active as well in addition to listing it in the script section but was unsuccessful in my attempts. I don't have an issue with the arrows just the indicator button dots below the carousel. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Thank you in advance.

```js
    function goRight() {
      document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft += 640;
    }
    function goLeft() {
      document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft -= 640;
    }
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
            var slide = document.getElementById("slide")
    btn[0].onclick = function goRight() {
                document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft += 640;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                btn[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            this.classList.add("active");
    }
        btn[1].onclick = function goRight() {
            document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft += 640;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               
                btn[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            this.classList.add("active");
        }
        btn[2].onclick = function goRight() {
            document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft += 640;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                btn[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            this.classList.add("active");
        }
       btn[3].onclick = function goRight() {
            document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft += 640;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                btn[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            this.classList.add("active");
        }
```

```css
.main_3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  margin: 5rem;
  width: 640px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-slide {
  height: 100%;
}

.main-slide>img {
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-show {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 310px;
  padding: 35px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  margin-right: 6rem;
}

.slide-show>p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000
}

.cta-btn-case-study {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.arrow>img {
  margin-top: 20rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.main-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.indicator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.indicator>.active {
  width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main_3">
 <div class="arrow">
            <img src="img/Left_arrow.png" alt="go to previous slide" >
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-container" id="slide">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="main-slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x150" alt="Dummy Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-show">
        <h1>Medical App</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et consequatur impedit et facere beatae aut aliquam sint eum quos delectus eum pariatur quia sed obcaecati itaque nam alias repudiandae.</p>
        <a href="Projects.html"><button class="cta-btn-case-study">View Case Study</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="main-slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x150" alt="Dummy Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-show">
        <h1>Fitness App</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et consequatur impedit et facere beatae aut aliquam sint eum quos delectus eum pariatur quia sed obcaecati itaque nam alias repudiandae.</p>
        <a href="Projects.html"><button class="cta-btn-case-study">View Case Study</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="main-slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x150" alt="Dummy Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-show">
        <h1>Sports Betting App</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et consequatur impedit et facere beatae aut aliquam sint eum quos delectus eum pariatur quia sed obcaecati itaque nam alias repudiandae.</p>
        <a href="Projects.html"><button class="cta-btn-case-study">View Case Study</button></a>
      </div>
<div class="carousel">
      <div class="main-slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x150" alt="Dummy Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-show">
        <h1>Sports Betting App</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et consequatur impedit et facere beatae aut aliquam sint eum quos delectus eum pariatur quia sed obcaecati itaque nam alias repudiandae.</p>
        <a href="Projects.html"><button class="cta-btn-case-study">View Case Study</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="arrow">
            <img src="img/Right_arrow.png" alt="go to next slide" >
        </div>

</section>
<div class="indicator">
  <span class="btn active"></span>
  <span class="btn"></span>
  <span class="btn"></span>
<span class="btn"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: goRight is not defined`

Comment: @Popnoodles The goRight has been defined. However, the issue is with the indicator buttons (in black) that sit below the carousel.

Comment: I think the problem is you're using `scrollLeft` on `.carousel-container` in one case and `translateX` on `slide` in another. You should only write code that does a thing once, and all buttons that do that thing should ultimately execute the one method. For example a `gotoSlide(slide_number)` method and `gotoNextSlide()` finds which slide is visible so knows which is next then calls `gotoSlide(...)`.

Comment: @Popnoodles I adjusted the code and was able to connect the images to the indicator button. The images slide right but unable to get them to slide left. I tried using another document.querySelector but making the .scrollLeft -= 640 a negative instead of a positive so it looked like so:

Comment: @Popnoodles
btn[0].onclick = function goRight() {
            document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft += 640;
            function goLeft() {
            document.querySelector(".carousel-container").scrollLeft -= 640;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                btn[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            this.classList.add("active");
    }